# Is it possible to stop Meteor DDP ping after a while?

Tags: meteor

In order to save server bandwidth I'd like to stop the DDP ping in meteor after a certain amount of time, and manually refresh the page if it regains user focus.
Is the DDP ping configurable? can I stop it after a while?

EDIT:

DDPRateLimiter can also save some bandwith but it wouldn't stop
http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#ddpratelimiter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using technique [described here](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-user-status/blob/master/client/main.js#L65) you may call `Meteor.disconnect()` if browser' window or tab looses focus, and `Meteor.reconnect()` when browser' window or tab is in focus again.

Sample code:

```
import { $ }           from 'meteor/jquery';
import { Meteor }      from 'meteor/meteor';

/* @description Set right visibilitychange event and property names */
const hidden = {};
hidden.str = false;
hidden.evt = void 0;

if (typeof document.hidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden.str = 'hidden';
  hidden.evt = 'visibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden.str = 'mozHidden';
  hidden.evt = 'mozvisibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden.str = 'msHidden';
  hidden.evt = 'msvisibilitychange';
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== 'undefined') {
  hidden.str = 'webkitHidden';
  hidden.evt = 'webkitvisibilitychange';
}

hidden.check = () => {
  return document[hidden.str];
};

$(document).on(hidden.evt, () => {
  if (hidden.check()) {
    Meteor.disconnect();
  } else {
    Meteor.reconnect();
  }
});
```

Comment: This does the trick, in the same context it's worth mentioning DDPRateLimiter to save bandwidth:  http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#ddpratelimiter